# In ggplot, how to manage width of rectangle when scale is discrete?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame with continuous y-values and a discrete x-value. For example:

```
x <- c("a", ..., "a" ,"b", ..., "b")
y <- c(1, 2, 14, 5, .....
```

I want to draw multiple rectangles, where the width of the rectangle depends on some other vector w.

```
w <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, ...)
```

If we assume that x is numeric, then I could do something like

```
ggplot() + geom_rect(xmin = x - w/2, xmax = x + w/2, ymin = ..., ymax = ...)
```

This would draw a rectangle for every (x,y) pair, with the width depending on the w-vector.

But how do I do this for a discrete x-axis? So I still want to change the width of the rectangle dependent on the w-vector, but I can't say

```
xmin = x - w/2
```

since x is a factor. I know I can get the plot by saying as.numeric(x), but then my scale changes to a number-scale, but I only want it to be the discrete "a", "b" scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I created a new column which is the numeric version of the factor column `x`, but then used `scale_x_continuous` to modify the axis such that it looks discrete.

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  x = c("a", "b", "c"),
  y = c(1, 4, 2),
  w = c(0.5, 1.2, 0.1)       
)

df$xn <- as.numeric(df$x)

ggplot(df, aes(xmin = xn - w / 2,
               xmax = xn + w / 2,
               ymin = y,
               ymax = y + 1,
               fill = x)) +
  geom_rect() + 
  scale_fill_discrete(guide = FALSE) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0.5),
                     labels = levels(df$x),
                     breaks = 1:length(levels(df$x))) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1, length(levels(df$x))))
```

[image]